# No provision for beneficiary at HSBC

Tags: united-states, bank-account, california, estate-planning

Background: My wife and I live in California (if that matters) and have a living trust.

My wife and I recently opened an online savings account at HSBC. APY is 2.01 which was the motivation.

HSBC has *no* provision to establish a beneficiary. I have reached out to them twice.

What happens if my wife and I die?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume the account is in the name of the trust... Wouldn't the trustees (you, your wife, etc.) be considered beneficiaries of the trust? The trust documents (and your will) should handle control and distribution of assets if both of you were to die...

Comment: That’s not the assumption I’d make. If it were true, no cause for concern.

Comment: Some major banks do not offer trust accounts but they do permit naming the trust as the beneficiary.  I briefly dealt with HSBC and quickly moved on because they are a mess.  Customer service calls often went unanswered for 5-10 minutes before disconnecting.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments! I completely overlooked the possibility to create the account in the name of the trust. Will check if this is an option at HSBC.

Comment: @BobT It is not necessary for a trustee (even of a living trust) to be a beneficiary of the trust, and unless both the will and the trust are set up correctly, the trust will own only those assets that are titled as belonging to the trust. The joint account in the name of the OP and spouse _does not_ belong to the trust.

Comment: @DilipSarwate The trust was created 2+ years ago and this is a new bank account. As such it is not listed in the trust. Would you say then that the best option is to find a bank that would accept a trust as a beneficiary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be a US/UK difference of terminology, but do/can bank accounts _have_ beneficiaries? As I understand it in the UK, if someone dies, an account in their name will be part of their estate and be handled according to any will or laws probate etc. If an account is in the name of a trust, the rules of the trust (or decision of its trustees) will decide what happens should someone connected with the trust die. The only thing I've seen where you can nominate a beneficiary is with certain pensions and life-assurance policies.

Comment: Update: HSBC required visiting a physical location to setup beneficiaries. However, beneficiaries must be real people and not a trust. Moved to American Express National Bank because they allowed creating an account and then re-titling the account to a trust. All online!

Comment: "What happens if my wife and I die?" - what does the law say? SOMEONE inherits the money, gtets a court document and the banks follow the court order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no beneficiaries are named on your account,that means that the account becomes part of your estate and passes per the terms of your will. Unfortunately, that means that your will will need to probated in court for the account to be transferred to the beneficiary names in your will (presumably your trust is the named beneficiary in your will for everything). So the end effect will be the same, but the timing will be affected. And if you were otherwise able to avoid having your estate in probated, this is going to muck it up.

If you still want the HSBC account but don’t want to worry about this, you could always open an account directly in the name of the Trust itself. While you are alive, you would have full control over it if it is a revocable living trust and you could treat it as your own account. Alternatively, if you are married, retitle the account as joint account with survivorship so the surviving spouse becomes the owner after the death of one you.

Answer (score 1):

My wife and I encountered nearly the same problem.  We recently opened an HSBC Direct Savings account online. After multiple phone calls I was informed that there was no way to assign beneficiaries to my account online, by phone or even through the mail.  The only way was to do it at one of their full service branches. Unfortunately, the closest HSBC branch to me is 5 hours away.